# Priority labelling in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am using GeoServer 2.2.1.

I have my maps then I want to see the largest cities before the small cities but I don't have population instead I have my PLACE column its not a numbers its a text example

```
NAME                PLACE          ADDRESS
Ayusan Norte        Village        VIGAN
Barangay VIII       Village        VIGAN
```

Then I want to create a big point to see all biggest cities.

How can I do that?

Comment: Largest in terms of what? Area?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried, but you should be able to get what you want using the "Recode" function, turning your labels into numbers.
Something like:

```
<Priority>
  <ogc:Function name="Recode">
     <ogc:PropertyName>PLACE</ogc:PropertyName>
     <ogc:Literal>Village</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>Town</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>City</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>Capital</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:Function>
</Priority>
```

See also examples in the documentation here: 
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/transformation-func.html#recode

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question. How do you differentiate a "big" city from a "small" city in your data?

The Geoserver SLD (styled layer descriptor) provides the means to apply styles based on attributes. The [SLD cookbook has an example](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html#attribute-based-point) for that. This attributed doesn't have to be population. It could be a text field containing "big" or "small". Then you can use a [filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) to check for one of these properties.

If you can provide more detail about your data, then I or someone here could help you with setting up the SLD file.